# ml-antlr or ml-ulex adding extra backslahed to output

Tags: parsing, antlr, sml, lexer

I've written a lexer and parser in ml-ulex and ml-antlr. (Running sml/nj)
I have a the following rule in my lexer:

```
<TRUSTED> [\"] => ( YYBEGIN INQUOTE ; Tokens.ValidText yytext );
```

It's identified correctly, but yytext has several additional '\' (backslashes)in the string. I get \\\\\\\" instead of \".

To make things more perplexing, I replaced the rule in my lexer with this one:

```
<TRUSTED> [\"] => ( YYBEGIN INQUOTE ; Tokens.DBLQUOTE );
```

And in my grammer I had the token
prod: DBLQUOTE    =>   ( "\"" );

With the same results as before....
If I replace the rule with

```
prod: DBLQUOTE    =>   ( "*test*" );
```

Then I get exactly one *test* as my string.

I've tried using String.fromString on the resulting string, and it doesn't do the trick. I'm not sure what's happening or why.